# create regular expression extractor for search icon and click using jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to make a regular expression extractor to below href tag to get the search icon in my code and needs to click on search icon in jmeter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all JMeter works on http/https/protocol requests and not on user actions

JMeter is not mainly used for functional testing.

When you are trying to achieve is functional part. JMeter will capture requests sent to server when user performs some action. It doesn't capture user actions. It will record request sent to server when user clicks on button1 but you cannot directly use same request with parameterized/extracted value i.e. button2 instead of button1. Reason behind this is that request may not be correct.

If you want to perform button clicks then there are other tools which mimic user actions and are configurable as JMeter.

I hope you are clear now about when to use JMeter :)